# For fn(z)= 1/nz, If we make fn(0)= 1, does that make the family of functions bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, limits

I have a problem that requires me to use a theorem requiring a bounded family of functions. The family provided that I am supposed to use this theorem for is $f_n (z) = \frac 1 {nz}$ when $z \neq 0$ and $f_n (0)=1$, $n \geq 1$.

However, I know that $\frac 1 z$ is not a bounded function as $\lim \limits _{z \to 0^+} \space \frac 1 z = \infty$ and $\lim \limits _{z \to 0^-} \space \frac 1 z = - \infty$.

What I don't get is how making $f_n (0) =1$ is going to somehow make this family bounded as the limits will still be going infinitely in opposite directions (and thus not be bounded).

If anyone could explain to me how removing the singularity at $0$ makes this family of functions bounded, that would be really appreciated. Because right now I can't see how it's bounded, and therefore don't believe I can even use the theorem for my problem.

Edit: The family of functions needs to be a bounded subset of the space of analytic functions $A(\Omega)$, for some domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$.

The question is to prove that the family of functions is equicontinuous at all $z \neq 0$ by using the following theorem: "Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a bounded subset of $A(\Omega)$. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous at each point of $\Omega$."

Comment: A few questions: (1) Is the common domain of these functions all of $\mathbb R$? (2) What is a "bounded family of functions" in this context? It must surely be different from a "family of bounded functions", since these functions don't appear to be bounded individually.

Comment: Maybe you can post the problem quoted exactly?

Comment: (1) no in **C** (complex numbers) sorry. (2) A Family of functions that is a bounded subset of the Analytic functions

Comment: Okay, thanks. My recollection is that there is a specific metric used with the space of analytic functions on a domain, but I will have to consult Conway to see what the metric is (don't recall details, sorry!). What is your text, BTW?

Comment: I edited to include the exact problem.

Comment: The problem isn't from my textbook, but the book we are using is: Complex Variables by R. B. Ash and W. P. Novinger. This problem is based on chapter 5 section 5.1, (and the theorem is 5.1.8)

Comment: There's the additional problem that the functions $f_n$ are not analytic at $0$, right? So something smells fishy here to me.

Comment: Yeah, this whole problem seems wrong to me- as though the family of functions cant be used for this theorem, I emailed my professor about it but he hasn't responded. I was hoping maybe someone here could see something I wasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the definition of equicontinuity, you see that for a given $\varepsilon$ there should exist a $\delta$ such that $|z_0 - z| < \delta\Rightarrow |f(z_0) - f(z)| < \epsilon,\;\forall n$. Take $z_0 = 0$. All this breaks, because for any $n$, the closer you get to $0$, the bigger is the difference between $f(z)$ and $f(0) = 1$, so if you choose any $\delta$, you can also choose $z: |z| < \delta$ such that for a given $n$, you have: $|\frac{1}{zn}| > \epsilon$.

In my opinion, this family is not equicontinuous in $0$. For other points, you choose $\delta$ that satisfies the continuity for $f_1$ and it should work for all other $n$, thus providing equicontinuity for a whole family.

N.B.: this family is definetely not uniformly equicontinuous even if you remove zero from your domain.

Comment: Thanks yeah the problem is to prove it where z_0 !=0 so i ended up using a really small number close to 0 on either side to show the functions are bounded when z is not zero, then i was able to use the theorem.